# Command line scaffolding in asp.Net VNext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a Web Application in Visual studio 2015 Preview. I am trying to create views using the Command Line Scaffolding. 
I used the following command:

```
k gen controller -name ProductController -m ViewModels.Product -dc ProductContext -f -udl
```

The `ViewModels.Product` class is defined in another project and referenced in UI project. I get the following error while running the command:

```
Finding the generator 'controller'...
Running the generator 'controller'...
Attempting to figure out the EntityFramework metadata for the model and DbContext.
The entity type 'ViewModels.Product' requires a key to be defined.
```

In the `Product` class I have added a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and defined a property with the `[key]` attribute.
It is creating the DataContext class, not views.

Anyone please suggest where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the scaffolding right now, as a work around, you can configure the Key in the generated DbContext's OnModelCreating method like this:

```
builder.Entity<Product>().Key(p => p.MyKeyName);
```

and then scaffold again.